concluding global lipschitz on a compact set from local lipschitz
What I'm given:
Let $U$ be an open supset of $\mathbb  R$ x  $\mathbb  R^d$ and $f$ $\in$ $C$(U, $\mathbb  R^d$ ) locally lipschitz-continuous regarding the second arguement. Let $K$ be a compat subset of $U$. Proof that the restriction $f$|$_K$ of $f$ on $K$ is globally lipschitz-continuous regarding the second argument. Please proceed as follows:
" Assume, the proposition does not hold, s. t. $\forall$ $n$ in $\mathbb N$ there exist $(t_n, x_n)$, $(t_n, y_n)$ $\in$ $K$ with:
$n|x_n - y_n| $$\lt$ |$f(t_n, x_n) - f(t_n, y_n)$|. (1.2)
Conclude the existence of subsequences $(t_{n_k}, x_{n_k})$, $(t_{n_k}, y_{n_k})$ with $(t_{n_k}, x_{n_k})$ $\rightarrow$ $(t^*, x^*)$ and $(t_{n_k}, y_{n_k})$ $\rightarrow$ $(t^*, y^*)$, where $(t^*, x^*)$, $(t^*, y^*)$ $\in$ $K$.
Use (1.2) and the continuity to conlude $x^* = y^*$."
My thoughts:
Since $f$ is not lipschitz in $K$ by assumption, (1.2) holds.
Since $K$ is compact, there exist converging subsequences $(t_{n_k}, x_{n_k})$, $(t_{n_k}, y_{n_k})$ with limits $(t^*, x^*)$, $(t^*, y^*)$ that lie within K. |$f(t_{n_k}, x_{n_k}) - f(t_{n_k}, y_{n_k})$| $\lt$ M $\in$ $\mathbb N$ since $K$ is compact and $f$ continuous.
$lim$ |$f(t_{n_k}, x_{n_k}) - f(t_{n_k}, y_{n_k})$| = |$f(t^*, x^*) - f(t^*, y^*)$|. (this is true becaus of continuity.)
And by assumption $\frac{|f(t^*, x^*) - f(t^*, y^*)|}{|(t^*, x^*) - (t^*, y^*)|}$ $\gt$ $n$. As this holds for all $n$, it follows that $(t^*, x^*) - (t^*, y^*)$ $\rightarrow$ $0$.'
I'm very bad with proofs in general (how i passed the first year is beyond me), but as this one came with instructions, I thought I should give it a very good try. My colleague also said how easy it was (and short), so I was optimistic.
(There is a second part of the exercise, but I would like to get this, the first, down before.)
My questions: are there any steps where I messed up? Is there a deep fault in logic? I don't want a solution per se, but more comments to help me.
